# Avoid memory errors when integrating large array with Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, out-of-memory

I have a `601x350x200x146` numpy `float64` array which, according to my calculations takes about 22.3 Gb of memory. My output of `free -m` tells me I have about 100Gb of free memory so it fits fine. However, when integrating with

```
result = np.trapz(large_arr, axis=3)
```

I get a memory error. I understand that this is because of the intermediate arrays that `numpy.trapz` has to create to perform the integration. But I'm looking to see if there's a way around it, or at least a way to minimize the extra use of memory.

I have read about memory errors and I know of things to avoid this: one is placing a `gc.collect()` call before the integration. I tried this and it didn't work.

The other one is using the `*=` operators such as writing `arr*=a` instead of `arr=arr*a`, which I can't really do here. So I don't know what else to try.

Does anyone know of a way to do this operation without raising a memory error?

You can reproduce the error with:

```
arr = np.ones((601,350,200,146), dtype=np.float64)
arr=np.trapz(arr, axis=3)
```

although you'll have to scale down the size to match your memory size.

Comment: It looks to me like that array is 49 gigabytes. NumPy makes a lot of use of intermediate scratch arrays; the `np.trapz` implementation needs more of those than your memory can hold.

Comment: Do you know what `trapz` is doing?  Even if ``arr` itself fits, temporary arrays created by `trapz` might not.

Comment: @user2357112 Yeah, that's what I thought. But what you're saying is that there's just no way?

Comment: Numexpr, Numba, or Cython could help, although you'd need to rewrite the `np.trapz` implementation instead of calling `np.trapz`. There's only about one line of actual math in it, though, and you don't need most of the boilerplate, so most of the hassle would be in installing and reading up on a new tool.

Comment: I think you might be able to get the memory usage down sufficiently in pure NumPy by being careful about in-place operations, but you still wouldn't be able to use `np.trapz` for the work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`numpy.trapz` provides some convenience, but the actual calculation is very simple.  To avoid large temporary arrays, just implement it yourself:

```
In [37]: x.shape
Out[37]: (2, 4, 4, 10)
```

Here's the result of `numpy.trapz(x, axis=3)`:

```
In [38]: np.trapz(x, axis=3)
Out[38]: 
array([[[ 43. ,  48.5,  46.5,  67. ],
        [ 35.5,  39.5,  52.5,  35. ],
        [ 44.5,  47.5,  34.5,  39.5],
        [ 54. ,  40. ,  46.5,  50.5]],

       [[ 42. ,  60. ,  55.5,  51. ],
        [ 51.5,  40. ,  52. ,  42.5],
        [ 48.5,  43. ,  32. ,  36.5],
        [ 42.5,  38. ,  38. ,  45. ]]])
```

Here's the calculation written to use *no* large intermediate arrays. (The slice `x[:,:,:,1:-1]` does not copy the data associated with the array.)

```
In [48]: 0.5*(x[:,:,:,0] + 2*x[:,:,:,1:-1].sum(axis=3) + x[:,:,:,-1])
Out[48]: 
array([[[ 43. ,  48.5,  46.5,  67. ],
        [ 35.5,  39.5,  52.5,  35. ],
        [ 44.5,  47.5,  34.5,  39.5],
        [ 54. ,  40. ,  46.5,  50.5]],

       [[ 42. ,  60. ,  55.5,  51. ],
        [ 51.5,  40. ,  52. ,  42.5],
        [ 48.5,  43. ,  32. ,  36.5],
        [ 42.5,  38. ,  38. ,  45. ]]])
```

If `x` has shape `(m, n, p, q)`, the few temporary arrays that are generated in that expression all have shape `(m, n, p)`.

Comment: Ah, of course. We can reduce the dimensions immediately, instead of at the last step. You can eliminate the remaining temporary arrays by using `+=` and `*=`, which could be a little helpful when reducing along a short axis, but the memory savings are small compared to the size of the input and the size of `np.trapz`'s temporaries.